# Element must be user-editable in order to clear it exception in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my below code I am executing

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(text(),'Create Part...')]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
        String subWindowHandler = null;

        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Type-Field']//following-sibling::div//div[@class='selectize-input items full has-options has-items']"));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys("Suba");
```

I am trying clear the default value in the field and giving some value through sendkeys. Field gives dropdown suggestions on entering the value.

It is throwing error at element.clear() line.

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: 
invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
(Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 
(437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 34 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 
09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'TMIC-PCS2200', ip: '3.235.34.200', os.name: 'Windows 7', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, 
mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome= 
{chromedriverVersion=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb), 
userDataDir=C:\Users\KT0047~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11272_22577}, 
takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, 
handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=66.0.3359.181, 
platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, 
acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, 
locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, 
takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, 
setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 742100fb9b41517012003fc5abe12b71
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me resolving my issue.
I am using Selenium 3.3.1 version.

HTML code

```
<div class="selectize-input items full has-options has-items" data-dropdown-direction="down">
<div data-value="Part" class="item">Part</div>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" style="width: 4px; position: relative; left: 0px; opacity: 0; z-index: -10000;">
::after
</div>
```

Here Part is the default value.

Comment: Try to set wait (with this -> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));) about 10s before element.clear();

Comment: Tried it. Still the same exception at the same line.

Comment: Update the question with the page HTML

Comment: HTML code included.

Comment: Are y sure for provided XPath? It seems very flaky? The problem is, your element is not found. Try with another locator strategy.

Comment: You are calling the `clear()` method on a WebElement that is pointing to a div tag. You can only call the `.clear()` on input tags. Try modifying the xpath such that it is pointing to the input tag below the div

Comment: Yeah tried it. But still the same error.

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selectize-input items full has-options has-items']//div[text()='Part']"));
   element.click();
   element.clear();
   element.sendKeys("Suba");

Comment: You are still trying to clear a div element! Clear only works when you call it on an input. Also you need to update the question with the full HTML

Comment: This is the new xpath ://select[@id='Type-Field']//following-sibling::div//div//input. Still the same error.

Comment: Now my xpath is reaching the input tag

Comment: @DebanjanB This should not have been flagged as a duplicate of that question. They are not the same error message or cause.

Comment: Are you sure the new xpath, `//select[@id='Type-Field']//following-sibling::div//div//input` actually reaches the correct input field? It is very generic at this point and may be pointing to a hidden input field, or a field that is disabled. Use Google Chrome console to test that it points to the right element. You also might try `//select[@id='Type-Field']//following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'selectize-input')]/div[contains(@class,'item')]/input` as something a little more directed.